# Knowledge of sexual relations using Jyotish

Tags: astrology, virginity

- Can astrology predict a native's spouse's virginity through his/her birth chart?
- If yes, what methods are used to find out the same?

Comment: Hello Rahul, Welcome to HSE. Though this question makes sense, I suggest you not to follow this in real life. Generally, following the astrology practices which everyone does before marriage should be enough. IMO, If you are committed, you should leave the past.

Comment: Astrology does not predict yes, no type question. Infact in case of gender prediction, Some astrologers (actually many) say we can, but infact gender cannot be predicted. So now you can guess what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

It can be known from trimśāmṣā (BPHS Chapter Stripuruśyoaḥ swabhāva viçaraḥ).

But let alone calculating ways of delineating varga charts, there is no universal consensus even for correct ayanāmśa which is important to have to arrive at correct divisional charts.